# Where does exchange 2003 store email?

Tags: exchange

What is the path to the default exchange email store?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the location on 'database' tab on the mailbox store properties.

Comment: I said default. I never said i did the setup on the box. Just had to find the mailstore by using a livecd. :)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it under C:\Program Files\Exchsrvr\mdbdata?